# Problems with Solidify

Tags: modeling

I'm looking to solidify this surface, however when I do the shading is strange. Autosmooth is already activated and my other solidified modifiers on other surfaces works as expected. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!
[Blender File Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10PQhEYp-Bgb4wnfEsI7uR8N168clwWmx?usp=sharing)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into the *Properties panel > Object Data > Geometry Data >* and *Clear Custom Split Normals Data*, it will reset the split normals which I guess created the problem:

[image]

Comment: That did it, thanks!